# Editing roughness factor with imperfection maps

Tags: texturing, shaders

So I downloaded roughness map with fingerprints but I need it to maintain roughness of a front part of the coin (0.25, highlighted part in second image). Is that possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a black and white texture and use it as mask to tell the shader where to apply the .25 value and where to apply fingerprints values.

If needed you can duplicate the Principled BSDF, have one with roughness .25 and one with the texture, and use the mask as factor of a Mix shader node, so that you can control every aspect of the two zones of the material.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Math* -> *Add* node to combine maps.

[image]

In this example I used the *Map Range* node to give the node output an average value of 0 so that I can control the value more easily.

Negative values exist here, but they are all represented by the color black.

In your case you'd start with a *Value* node and add in the effect you want.

[image]